# Plugin for MongoDB in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, mongodb

I'm developing an application for a client based on Vue and NodeJS.

Earlier MS Access database was used and I have migrated it to MongoDB and also to PostgreSQL in case I don't find any plugin for MongoDB.

I would like to know is there any recently updated plugin of QGIS for MongoDB or I need to use PostGIS with PostgreSQL?

I found 1 plugin but it was last updated in 2016.

Comment: What do you mean by `"...is there any recently updated plugin of QGIS for MongoDB..."`? Do you want to connect your DB in QGIS, or what? Or what should be the purpose of the plugin? Which QGIS version do you deploy? There are [some plugins](https://plugins.qgis.org/search/?q=MongoDB) based on the "MongoDB" search.

Comment: If the plugin works and is stable it doesn't really matter if it hasn't been updated since 2016. You might provide a link to it.